# Voltage divider with a short, what is Vout?

Tags: voltage-divider, short-circuit

**Figure 1:**

```
            A                 B
Vin---====-----====--+--====-----GND
       R1       R2   |   R3
                     |
                    Vout
```

In this basic voltage divider, \$V_{out}\$ is calculated as:

$$V_{out} = \frac{R3}{R1 + R2 + R3} \times V_{in}$$

**Figure 2:**

```
            A                 B
            +-----------------+
Vin---====--+--====--+--====--+--GND
       R1       R2   |   R3
                     |
                    Vout
```

In Figure 2, a short is made between points A and B.

Will there be a voltage at \$V_{out}\$?

If so, how is it calculated?

EDIT:  A follow-up to this question is posted here: [Voltage divider with short circuit part 2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/110198/voltage-divider-with-short-circuit-part-2)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE.  FYI.  We have a CircuitLab schematic editor on EE.SE.  There is a `Schematic` button on the toolbar, when you edit the question.  So, no need to do the ASCII art.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A correct answer has been given in words.  But you also asked "how is it calculated".

I've redrawn figure 2 for clarity.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5VE9L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, it might not be obvious that this is the same circuit as your figure 2 but, in fact, it is.

Assuming the Vout node is not connected to any other circuit, we can *calculate* Vout as follows:

By inspection, R2 and R3 have the same voltage across and thus, the current 'down' through each resistor is, by Ohm's law:

$$I_{R2} =  \frac{V_{out}}{R_2}$$

$$I_{R3} =  \frac{V_{out}}{R_3}$$

Now, applying [Kirchhoff's Current Law](http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/elessonshtml/Basic/Basic4Ki.html) (KCL) at the output node, we have

$$I_{R2} +  I_{R3} = 0$$

Combining the previous equations, we have

$$\frac{V_{out}}{R_2} +  \frac{V_{out}}{R_3} = 0$$

The only solution to this equation is

$$V_{out} = 0$$

Now, as you gain more experience with solving circuits, this result will not require any calculation at all - the result will become part of your circuits intuition and will be obvious by inspection.

Answer (score 1):

Once the short circuit is applied from A to B, then A is at the same potential as GND.  Any current flowing through R1 will bypass R2 and R3, since there is a low-impedance path around them.

Since there is no current flowing through R2 an R3, the voltage at the Vout node will be zero.

Comment: This isn't a homework problem, I'm just learning electronics and am playing with a resistor ladder connected to a keypad that when you press a button shorts across two pins.  At any rate, I see how it could be a homework problem as it's pretty basic.  Thank you for your answer I'll go work on it :)

Comment: @par Excellent! That'll teach me to make assumptions :)  I've edited the answer.

Comment: Just to give you another way to look at this, when the switch is closed, R2 and R3 form a divider between 0 V and 0 V, and R1 becomes irrelevant to setting Vout. Any (unloaded) divider between equal potential points will have that same potential at the output, so you get the answer by inspection.

Comment: @ThePhoton, +1. I *almost* wrote that as an answer.  By superposition, \$V_{out} = V_A \frac{R_3}{R_2 + R_3} + V_B \frac{R_2}{R_2 + R_3} = 0 \frac{R_3}{R_2 + R_3} + 0 \frac{R_2}{R_2 + R_3}\$